# How do I multiply the result of previous multiplication by 2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I want to multiply $2\times 2=4$ and multiply the result (this case $4$) times $2$ the times I want.

For example I want this $2\times 2 = 4$, $4\times 2 = 8$, $8\times 2 = 16$ in big scale.  Something like this $a\times 2 = \text{result} \times 2\times x$

where $a$= initial number, $x=$ times I want this to happen.

Comment: Your question isn't really legible in its current format and it isn't really clear what you're asking. Perhaps you could ask a bit more clearly. From what I can decipher it seems like what you're looking for is something like

$$f(x) = 2^xa$$

so that for a number $a$, you will double it $x$ times.

Comment: Are you looking for a sequence? You have some number $x_0$, then say $x_1=2x_0, x_2=2x_1$, and so on, so in general, $x_n=2^nx_0$.

Comment: It's wierd I known, see this example. 2*2 = 4 ; 4*2=8  ; 8*2=16, I am multiplying the result of a previous multiplication *2, 3 times, which equals 16, I wanted to know if there is a way to get to the result by a formula imagining I wanted to do this 50 times instead of 3 times

Comment: @KevinLong Yes! That's what I was looking for! Also ÍgjøgnumMeg thanks for helping aswell!

Answer (score 1):

You can try power of 2. Example:
$a \times 2^{3} = a \times 2 \times 2 \times 2$.
In a more general way $ a \times 2^{x}$ where $a$ is the initial number and $x$ the number of times you want this to happen.